# label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: c#

Hello I have a problem with this code, when i press the button i get the following ERROR : Incorrect syntax near 'Text:'. 
The label 'Text' has already ben declare.Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
The label 'Text' has already ben declare.Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

```
private void DodajDelavcaa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(global::Easy_Podjetnik.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            string Spoll = "";
            if (RB_M.Checked)
            {
                Spoll = "Moški";
            }
            else if (RB_Z.Checked)
            {
                Spoll = "Ženski";
            }

            string sql = "INSERT INTO Delavci(Ime, Priimek, Spol, Leto_Rojstva, Placa) values(" + AddIme + "," + AddPriimek + "," + Spoll + "," + Add_Datum + "," + PlacaD + ")";
            SqlCommand exeSql = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            exeSql.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Congrtz", "Good" ,MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I really, really suggest you to search for 'parameterized queries'

Comment: Anyway, what is the schema of your table 'Delavci' and how are declared the variables that you have put in the VALUES part of your query?

Comment: What are the data types for your Table Delavci? Try `values('" + AddIme + "','" + AddPriimek + "','" + Spoll + "','" + Add_Datum + "','" + PlacaD + "')"` (addition of `'` in the values section) You should also be using parameters, not a raw sql string as this opens you to sql injection but that's a separate matter

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Delavci] (
    [Id]           INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Ime]          NCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    [Priimek]      NCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    [Spol]         NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [Leto_Rojstva] DATETIME   NOT NULL,
    [Placa]        MONEY      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

Tabel Delavci

Comment: @Ghost it really helped.. missed 'single quotes' before and after values and so got this error..

Answer (score 1):

Very likely this is caused by an error in an Insert Trigger on your `Delavci` table.  That is not the only possibility, but it is the most likely one.

If it is not that, then likely the only way to catch it would be to use trace/profiler on your SQL Server.

---

Hmm, given that you are compositing your SQL statement (instead of using parameters, as recommended) this could also be caused by bad data in your `Values(..)` variables.  To check this, use `Debug.Print` to record the actual text of the SQL command before you execute it.